# What level of public support did Adolf Hitler have in his final year of power?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, hitler, fascism

In his final year in power, what level of support did Adolf Hitler still command and what drove that public perception?

I ask as an insight into populism and at what point do populations reach a tipping point where they turn on the leader who promised them a return to glory.

**Did this ever occur** or did the German population defend Adolf Hitler into the years after his demise even after the discovery of the concentration camps and the defeat of the German militaries?

Comment: How would you measure this? Would you trust any public opinion poll or vote in a fascist state?  (I'm not challenging, I'm just trying to figure out how I would approach the problem.)

Comment: I don't know...that's why I asked in History SE :-)  I am assuming there must be academic and informed WW2 researchers or enthusiasts here that could give a well informed answer.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace -- your first reaction was the same as mine, even before I clicked in to read the full post. "Was anyone running Gallup polls in Nazi Germany? Would people give their honest opinions to a pollster if they were afraid of the Gestapo?" And so forth. I conjecture that, after the war, it might be commonplace for Germans to say: "I realized years ago that Hitler was crazy, but I didn't dare *say* anything," and how would you prove that they were lying or telling the truth?

Comment: Excellent point - to use a different example, although Richard Nixon was elected by a majority of Americans the only person who will admit to voting for him is my mother (who still believes him to be innocent of all charges).  History can ill afford to rely on recollection of non-recorded facts.  This question may be unanwerable.

Comment: I will issue a bounty in 2 days.  Let's see what the community can come up with.

Comment: It's impossible to quantify. But on the 20th of July 1944, German army officers tried to overthrow Hitler. Their worldview was pretty similar to Nazism (for those who weren't actually Nazis). So it's reasonable to suppose that many people who were less wedded to the idea of martial glory etc also had a few doubts.

Comment: Spoke to my professional historian girlfriend, who said common historical practice is to analyze the change in (1) underground press, (2) official press stories on resistance activities and (3) number and type of arrest records for dissent.  The absolute measurement is meaningless, but the rate of change is a proxy for public support. HOpe that helps someone find something.

Comment: Professional historian girlfriend.  I feel like you are going out with a Lara Croft type character.  Don't burst the bubble :-D

Comment: I feel that way too.....

Comment: MPHG (My Professional Historian Girlfriend) also points out that she rides sidesaddle - much like Lara Croft at the beginning of the Tomb Raider movie... I'm just sayin.....

Comment: Marriage material.

Comment: Required reading: [The End: Hitler's Germany 1944–45](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End:_Hitler%27s_Germany_1944%E2%80%9345) by Ian Kershaw.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, this could be measured if any "internal" documents, reports of the German security services existed on that matter. I doubt that there is any viable government not interested in the public opinion about itself. So even if Gestapo suppressed overt expression of "discontent" they definitely must have been doing some work on assessing it. So this is how such matters could be measured (obviously with caution), if these materials survived.

Comment: Consider the counterfactual - Hitler maintained the level of popularity he achieved after successfully invading Poland and France, right through the failed Russian campaign,and even as it became clear Germany was going to lose the war between 1943 and the eventual surrender.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38593/how-did-the-civilian-population-of-nazi-germany-react-to-operation-overlord/38601#38601); the book I refer to provides much more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A historian named David Bankier wrote a classic book in the 1960s called *The Germans and the Final Solution: Public Opinion under Nazism*. Bankier argues (as quoted in [a student book review](http://www.history.ucsb.edu/faculty/marcuse/classes/133b/133bproj/09proj/essays/Bankier1996Hedgpeth093.htm)) that “unprecedented political apathy, coupled with the conservative and clerical oppositionist attitudes” shaped strategic decisions in 1936 and 1937. This doesn't support the kind of "turning point" the questions asks for, but it does suggest that negative public opinion had relevance to the Nazi regime.

Comment: just wanted to let you know that I have found a second hand copy of this and purchased it.  Thank you.