# When did Germans stop supporting Adolf Hitler?

Tags: nazi-germany, social-history

I know that  German Reich with the leadership of Adolf Hitler was a dictatorship, however I think, at least in some part of history the majority of Germans supported him and his ideologies. [This article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4899-6084-9_5) claims that Hitler was very popular in between Germans. Also [this article](https://www.thoughtco.com/who-supported-hitler-and-why-1221371) says the Nazies had a wide range of supporting group.

But, i believe in some point of history the majority of people stop supporting him. I know there were **[German resistance to Nazism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_resistance_to_Nazism)** since 1933, but they were individuals or small groups. But, here i am talking about the majority of society.

My questions is, since when Germans stop supporting Hitler? In other word, what made Germans revise about their opinion?

Comment: May 8, 1945; V-E Day.

Comment: Doues this answer your question https://history.stackexchange.com/q/50963 or this  https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/what-level-of-public-support-did-adolf-hitler-have-in-his-final-year-of-power?rq=1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure how one would measure this; how do you distinguish between the public support required of a dictator and private opinions?  There are consequences for failing to support fascism.  Support could have been 1%, so long as people were afraid to express their discontent for fear of persecution.

Comment: The accepted answer to [*How did attitudes of German citizens toward Hitler and the Nazi Party change over the course of the pre-war and the post-war periods?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50963/how-did-attitudes-of-german-citizens-toward-hitler-and-the-nazi-party-change-ove) covers this quite well (see around the half-way point onwards).

Comment: Please keep in mind that the standards for questions about Nazi Germany are higher due to issues with trolling and neo-Nazi content. Please read: https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3473/21290

Answer (score 2):

As Pieter said in comment, May the 8th 1945 should be chosen for the event you're speaking of.

Why? Well, because if during the dictatorship from 1933 to 1939, people could still enter resistance, the Germans were still mostly supporting or passive about nazism and Hitler.

Then came the war: from this point, the war triggered two factors:

- By that time, most of the population was patriotic, even if it was not nazi. This was notably true for some German, aristocratic generals that thought nazism was low-people politics. They thought they were above that, but overall they were patriotic so they stayed loyal
- The war triggered more control of the society, and it was seen even worse to be critical against th Nazis

Note that resistance was still possible: for example, Operation Walkyrie.

So the point is that during the war, there was no tangible sign that Hitler was not supported anymore. And it is mostly because no such signs could express, except for an uprising that never came.
So on May, 8th 1945 there was a brutal change. And it seems that the Germans, considering the Shoah and the disaster for Germany at the end of the war (death, destruction, foreign occupation), changed their minds quickly.

Answer (score -1):

There is no strong evidence that, given a free choice, a majority of Germans *ever* supported the Nazis.

The [Weimar Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimar_Republic) was a multiparty proportional-representation [Parliamentary Democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_system). Under such systems, its quite common for no one party to hold a majority.

In the [last legitimately Democratic election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/July_1932_German_federal_election) in that nation, the Nazi party secured only 37% of the vote. That was more than any other party in the nation, and enough that it probably wouldn't be feasible to form a government without them in the ruling coalition. However, its a fact that nearly **two thirds of Germans in that election wanted someone else**.

Looking over the results, it looks like there was one other right wing party that won seats in that election, with about another 5% of the vote. None of the rest of the top parties were anywhere near as right-wing as the Nazis. This means two things: First, that it looks like they scooped up nearly all far-right voters that election, and Second, that the vast majority of the country did *not* want a government on that end of the political spectrum.

Comment: "there is a strong consensus among historians and eye-witnesses that Hitler's popularity soared in the early years of his regime as he delivered on his economic promises [...]" ([link](http://www.valkyrie-plot.com/hitler.html)).

Comment: All socialists, whether *national* or *international*, are left wing. Stop perpetuating lies about the political spectrum. In the Berlin transit Workers Strike just a few months before the election you reference, the Nazi and Communist strikers ate lucnh together for 3 days.

Comment: "The Third Reich was not a dictatorship maintained by force.  Indeed, the Nazi leadership developed an almost fearful preoccupation with the mood of the populace, which they monitored carefully, devoting considerable energy and resources toward fulfilling consumer desires, even to the detriment of the country's rearmament program." ([link](http://www.worldfuturefund.org/wffmaster/Reading/Germany/Hitler.popular.htm))

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Umm... if you are trying to say the Nazis weren't right wing, that is pretty much the opposite of the consensus opinion on the subject. See **very first sentence** of the [Nazi WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party). I suppose you're still free to consider that "lies", but the comments of this answer isn't the proper place to argue your unusual take on the subject.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Its mainstream - despite what over-eager minimum-wage interns care to publish on questionable internet sites. The racial baiting that the Nazis engaged in on top of class distinction, would perfectly characterize today's very left wing Democratic Party.

Comment: It's modern double-speak. Ayn Rand would be right-wing.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Again, this isn't the place to be having this discussion. The question here is whether the statement made **in the post** is a supportable statement, and the *fact* is that it is. If you don't like it, and want it to be changed, I'd need much better against it than crude name-calling. If you instead just have a contrarian position you'd like to promote, I'd like to think there's a good place for that, but this isn't it.

Comment: @TomasBy - Actually, I don't disagree with anything on that website, and honestly could easily have cut and paste some of it into this answer as quotes. What its saying is that most historians think his popularity *probably* went way up (over a rather low starting point) afterwards, but it also takes pains to point out that *we really have no way to know*. Which is pretty much what this answer says.

Comment: Given the fact that the Nazis got about 1/3 of the vote democratically in a highly divided political system, when they did have a choice, your argument is faulty.

Comment: Nazis were gangsters in uniform . . . all pushing their latest of the month for self aggrandizement or wealth accumulation.  The massacre of millions for whatever reason was just to perpetuate a wealth gathering system.  Everybody benefited until they did not at which post enthusiasm started to fall off.

Comment: 37% is a very high voter support in countries which did not stuck in a 2 party system.

Comment: @T.E.D. No. "Difficult to know"? This is *not* what this answer says. This answer frames the problem as the Martian-Nazis descended and enslaved & brainwashed a populace which was coerced but didn't support, thus it's exculpable. The first line is utterly misleading. As is the rest — as you extrapolate *everything* from 1932 forward. As limited as election results go, you must then also look at a later, free, open, democratic one: Saar-plebiscite with 90% supporting Hitler in 1935.

Comment: @LаngLаngС - Um, no, no words like that were used. All this answer is saying is that there is no *proof* there was ever a majority support for that party. That certainly shouldn't exculpate anyone. In fact, if you disagree with what's going on, but just stay quiet and "go along to get along", in my mind that's much worse.

Comment: No. 1. This A focuses on that one election & discounts all other evidence as 'no proof' (Mar33 & Saar35 are elections as well. Elections are not everything) 2. you seem to overly rely on the qualifier "no strong", while jumping ahead to "vast majority not want" in the end & at bottom of A. That's demonstrably utterly wrong for the most part of those 12 years. // You need to rephrase urgently the 1st & last sentences. Including that you *only* talk about 32–feb33 and 'fair elections'. But w/o additions, that then *does not answer the Q posed here*…